# How to work with mulitple domains in a single app? ASP.net core 3.0 (razor pages, azure)

Tags: c#, azure, .net-core, azure-web-app-service, razor-pages

I am expanding my website to another country.
It's basically a listing of events.
I'd like to only show events from belgium if domain is {companyname}.be, only events from the netherlands if {companyname}.nl etc.

To keep the costs down I want this to work in a single azure web app, so I'd need to get the domain name from the request since I cannot set this in configuration.

I know i can get the current domain by using

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Host
```

But I feel I'm missing some "best practice" approach. Something that would also work in development and preproduction environments.. any documentation you know of that could help me out?

Comment: You can try my solution first to see if it meets your needs. I am also studying whether it is possible to bind multiple domain names. On Monday, I will let you know the latest results.

Comment: Is my answer what you need? Or if you need other help, please let me know and look forward to your reply.

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE**

I have mapped multiple custom domains to my web app. It works well, the result as below.

[image]

[image]

**PRIVIOUS**

we also can use second-level domain names to fulfill your needs. You can use `be.websitename.com` to access on behalf of Belgian users.

```
//Home/getUrl
public IActionResult getUrl() {
     string url = HttpContext.Request.Host.Value;
     return Content(url);
}
```

You can set your second-level domain in your portal. Like pic.

[image]

Then you can test it by broswer.

[image]

[image]